# Printing a HTML + JavaScript variable from an external js to an index.html file using fetch + node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fetch-api

I was under the impression I could use node.js to do this but you cannot b/c of reasons given by the answer. Essentially I just wanted to use `fetch` and that's all you really need. Here is a very basic way of using it.

```js
async function fetch_weather() {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=90210,us&appid={API-KEY}&units=imperial');
    const weather = await response.json();
    document.querySelector("#weather").innerHTML =

<table>
<caption>Current weather data using <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch" target="_blank"><code>fetch</code></a></caption>
<br>

<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>City/State</th>
    <th>Current Temp</th>
    <th>Feels Like:</th>
    <th>Longitude:</th>
    <th>Latitude:</th>
    <th>Sunrise (Unix)</th>
    <th>Sunset (Unix)</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>${weather.name}, GA</td>
    <td>${weather.main.temp}</td>
    <td>${weather.main.feels_like}</td>
    <td>${weather.coord.lon}</td>
    <td>${weather.coord.lat}</td>
    <td>${weather.sys.sunrise}</td>
    <td>${weather.sys.sunset}</td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>

};
```

Here  was the non-working node.js code:

`index.js`

```
import fetch from './node-fetch';

async function fetchWeatherJSON() {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/.../&appid={API-KEY}');
    const weather = await response.json();
    return weather;
}

fetchWeatherJSON().then(weather => {
document.querySelector("#weather").innerHTML = `Longitude: ${weather.coord.lon}`
    console.log(`Longitude: ${weather.coord.lon}`);
    console.log(`Latitude: ${weather.coord.lat}`);
    console.log(`Current Temp: ${weather.main.temp}`);
    console.log(`Feels Like: ${weather.main.feels_like}`);
    console.log(`Sunrise: ${weather.sys.sunrise}`);
    console.log(`Sunset: ${weather.sys.sunset}`);
    console.log(`City/State: ${weather.name}, GA`);
});
```

Inside fetchWeatherJSON().then(...) part I tried things like

```
document.querySelector("#weather").innerHTML = `Longitude: ${weather.coord.lon}`;
```

but none of those types of ways worked. I have no idea if there is just something I am doing wrong here as far as selectors or this isn't the best way (or any way) to do it.

I'd like to print this to an index.html page, here is a simple example of some HTML. It would be nice to be able to print whatever is shown the javascript console inside the opening an close `<p>` elements.

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Node.js Weather App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Node.js Weather App</h2>
    <div id="weather"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code cannot work. Not on node.js nor on the browser because:

1. Node.js has no `fetch` built in, so you need an extra library for it. For this you use `node-fetch`. But in the same .js file you try to access DOM elements with `document.`. Dom elements does not exist in Node.js, only inside the browser.
2. This code wont work, because usually you have an bundler like Vite or webpack that bundles your npm packages. Anyway, `node-fetch` is only made for Node.js, not for the browser.

The browser already has an built-in `fetch`.

Comment: Thanks, that kept me from continually going down the rabbit hole. :) I'll update my post with how I got it to work with just `fetch` after I make sure everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Set a console.log to check if "weather" has any value.
Also, your QuerySelector is wrong:

> document.querySelector("#weatherHTML")

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong type of query selector: `document.querySelector("weatherHTML")` will select elements named accordingly (`<weatherHTML></weatherHTML>`).

You should use `document.querySelector("#weatherHTML")` to select the element with the corresponding id.

This is also equivalent to `document.getElementById("weatherHTML")`

Using this principle, this is the new fetchWeatherJSON callback:

```js
fetchWeatherJSON().then(weather => {
    console.log(`Longitude: ${weather.coord.lon}`);
    console.log(`Latitude: ${weather.coord.lat}`);
    console.log(`Current Temp: ${weather.main.temp}`);
    console.log(`Feels Like: ${weather.main.feels_like}`);
    console.log(`Sunrise: ${weather.sys.sunrise}`);
    console.log(`Sunset: ${weather.sys.sunset}`);
    console.log(`City/State: ${weather.name}, GA`);

    document.querySelector("#weatherHTML").innerHTML = `Longitude: ${weather.coord.lon}...`
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected that, I think it was a typo on my end though, I should always copy and paste. When I try, the error I get is: `index.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at index.js:1:1)
`  Here is the actual website so everyone can test it a bit easier. Maybe it helps some. https://j1m3.xyz/weather/index.html